No Input Devices in Sound settings
I bought a new laptop Hp Victus 15. I have installed ubuntu 24.04 and 22.04 also multiple times. But In sound Settings shows No input devices.Audio input was working in Windows. My kernel version is 6.8.0-40-generic. It would be a great help if you have a solution. Thanks in abvanced

What have you done to troubleshoot this?

tried to update drivers and some random stuff found in internet regrading this issue. can't remember them
